# meaning of comma operator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understood simple concepts about comma operator in python. For instance,

```
x0, sigma = 0, 0.1
```

means x0=0, and sigma=0.1. But I obtained a code that has a line that looks like the following.

```
y, xe = np.histogram(np.random.normal(x0, sigma, 1000))
```

where the output of y and xe are the followings.

```
y
Out[10]: array([  3,  17,  58, 136, 216, 258, 189,  87,  31,   5], dtype=int64)

xe
Out[11]: 
array([-0.33771565, -0.27400243, -0.21028922, -0.146576  , -0.08286279,
       -0.01914957,  0.04456364,  0.10827686,  0.17199007,  0.23570329,
        0.2994165 ])
```

I am not sure how to read y, xe expression. What could I look up to understand what it's saying?

Comment: Answerers, please be aware that the question is not about the `x0, sigma = 0, 0.1` line. It's about the `y, xe = np.histogram(np.random.normal(x0, sigma, 1000))` line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`x0, sigma = 0, 0.1` is syntactic sugar. Some stuff is happening behind the scenes:

- `0, 0.1` implicitly creates a tuple of two elements.
- `x0, sigma =` unpacks that tuple into those two variables.

If you look at the docs for [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), you see that it returns these two things:

```
hist : array
The values of the histogram. See density and weights for a description of the possible semantics.

bin_edges : array of dtype float
Return the bin edges (length(hist)+1).
```

Your `y, xe = ...` unpacks the tuple of the two returned arrays respectively. That is why your `y` is assigned to a numpy int64 array and your `xe` assigned to a numpy float array.

Comment: Actually `x0, sigma = 0, 0.1` doesn't even create the tuples - that's one of the few cases where Python optimizes the code (and avoids creating the tuples). However Python "could" create the tuples and that it doesn't is an "implementation detail" if I remember correctly.

Comment: @MSeifert Yeah, I could imagine something like that would be optimized by removing the overhead of creating a new tuple only if it is going to be assigned via unpacking. Never looked too deep into that though :P

Answer (score 11):

A comma forms a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple), which in Python looks just like an immutable list.

Python does *destructuring assignment*, found in a few other languages, e.g. modern JavaScript. In short, a single assignment can map several left-hand variables to the same number of right-hand values:

```
foo, bar = 1, 2
```

This is equivalent to `foo = 1` and `bar = 2` done in one go. This can be used to swap values:

```
a, b = b, a
```

You can use a tuple or a list on the right side, and it will be unpacked (destructured) the same way if the length matches:

```
a, b = [1, 2]
# same effect as above:
xs = [1, 2]
a, b = xs
# again, same effect using a tuple:
ys = 1, 2
a, b = ys
```

You can return a tuple or a list from a function, and destructure the result right away:

```
def foo():
  return (1, 2, 3)  # Parens just add readability

a, b, c = foo()  # a = 1; b = 2; c = 3
```

I hope this answers your question. The histogram function returns a 2-tuple which is unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution for you:

```
def func():
    return 'a', 3, (1,2,3)  # returns a tuple of 3 elements (str, int, tuple)

x1, x2, x3 = func()  # unpacks the tuple of 3 elements into 3 vars
# x1: 'a'
# x2: 3
# x3: (1,2,3)
```

Comment: This is a good illustration, but you need to explain what is happening and why it works.