# Python - Inserting dictionary into SQLite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I got a dictionary with 14 keys.

First Ive created `createTableOfRecordsenter` function:

```
    def createTableOfRecords(self):
        create_table = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records(Budget TEXT , Commitment TEXT, Contract_Type TEXT , Customer_Type TEXT, Duration TEXT , Goals TEXT, Pace TEXT , 
                        Procedures_and_Regulations TEXT, Resources TEXT , Scope TEXT, Team_Availability TEXT , Team_Distribution TEXT, Team_Size TEXT , Uncertainty TEXT);'''
        self.cursor.execute(create_table)
        self.connection.commit()
```

and the table with columns created successfully.
After that, I tried to insert the data using the `insertRecords` function:

```
    global var_dict
    var_dict = dict(Budget="Fixed",
                    Commitment="Low",
                    Contract_Type="Hybrid",
                    Customer_Type="Market",
                    Duration="Long",
                    Goals="Unclear",
                    Pace="Fast",
                    Procedures_and_Regulations="None",
                    Resources="Standart",
                    Scope="Rigid",
                    Team_Availability="Fully",
                    Team_Distribution="Global",
                    Team_Size="Small",
                    Uncertainty="Predictable")

    def insertRecords(self):
        self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO records (Budget,Commitment,Contract_Type,Customer_Type,Duration,Goals,Pace,'
                                                 'Procedures_and_Regulations,Resources,Scope,Team_Availability,'
                                                 'Team_Distribution,Team_Size,Uncertainty) '
                            'VALUES (:Budget, :Commitment, :Contract_Type, :Customer_Type, :Duration, '
                                    ':Goals, :Pace, :Procedures_and_Regulations, :Resources, :Scope, :Team_Availability, '
                                    ':Team_Distribution, :Team_Size, :Uncertainty);'), var_dict
        self.connection.commit()
```

but I didn't get any value inserted into the database table.
I got this error message:

`self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO records (Budget,Commitment,Contract_Type,Customer_Type,Duration,Goals,Pace,' sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 14, and there are 0 supplied.`

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : How to insert a dictionary to a sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913080/python-how-to-insert-a-dictionary-to-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python and SQLite: insert into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092757/python-and-sqlite-insert-into-table)

Comment: You're not passing your dict as an argument to `execute`... Gotta pay attention to your parenthesis.

Comment: Both answers above are good and I've seen them but still not manage to execute the code. @Shawn What do you mean?

Comment: I've pasted the Error message, tried to google it but didn't found anything helpful.

Comment: `var_dict` should be second parameter for `self.cursor.execute`  ie `self.cursor.execute(command, var_dict)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written:

```
self.cursor.execute( 'insert ...' ), var_dict
```

`var_dict` is not being passed as an argument to `execute`. It is outside the parenthesis. Instead you are [making a two element tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574730/meaning-of-comma-operator-in-python) of the result of `execute` and `var_dict` and then throwing it out.

You want to pass var_dict into execute like so.

```
self.cursor.execute( 'insert ...', var_dict )
```

Here's a quick illustration of the difference.

```
>>> var_dict = dict(foo="bar")
>>> def test(sql, *optional):
...     print(f"Got sql '{sql}' and args {optional}\n")
... 
>>> test('insert...'), var_dict
Got sql 'insert...' and args ()

(None, {'foo': 'bar'})
>>> test('insert...', var_dict)
Got sql 'insert...' and args ({'foo': 'bar'},)
```